# php - used memory seems off

Tags: php, memory, integer

So... in theory an int has 4/8 bytes (depending on 32/64 bit system). That would mean that 4 million ints should be about 32 mb.

Yet... I made the following script:

```
    $mem = memory_get_usage(true);
    $a = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4000000; $i++) {
        $a[$i] = $i;
    }
    dump(number_format(memory_get_usage(true) - $mem / 1048576, 2));
```

And the result is ~140 mb consistently. Scaled to 8 mil and 16 mil to check and the results where rather consistent again (~260 mb and ~520 mb). So is clear that the memory is used by the array.

What I don't understand is... why that much of a difference?
Some garbage collector fail? Or... some type issue? I fail to get where is the huge difference coming from. If I consider the indexes of the array I still get to ~64 mb in theory. Where is the rest coming from?

Comment: PHP is a high level language. It doesn't use ints, it uses a data structure called zval.

Comment: Also, and I don't know much about the internals of PHP arrays, but I'm pretty certain you are storing `$i` twice, once for the key and once for the value

Comment: Regardless, there's a great [blog post](https://www.npopov.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html) by Nikita that dives into it. It is for PHP 5, but he talks about PHP 7 and links to a similar article.

Comment: The last comment contains the answer.